# How to find out the error when a csv file won't be uploaded by php?

Tags: php, csv, import

I'm creating csv files and uploading them into my PHP application.

I create every file the same way, and just change the content every time. I do this in order to import information manually from one site to another.

My problem is that one csv file is not read properly.

What I've done with the attachment field in the form is putting it into a variable and var_dump the variable:

```
$adjunto = $_FILES['adjunto'];
var_dump($adjunto);
```

And here's the result:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(20) "importArticulos1"
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error"]=>
  int(1)
  ["size"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Other files do upload without issues:

```
array(5) { when 
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "importJuris"
  ["type"]=>
  string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpzC2FAM"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(1881617)
}
```

My question is: **How can I know more about the error when a file is simply not read or not recognized?**

By the way, the error log tells me this:

> [18-Aug-2019 08:23:20 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Warning: 
>   fopen(/home/rosamunda/public_html/importar.csv): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/rosamunda/public_html/demo1.php on line 131

The line 131 tries to open the file with `fopen()` which won't open because the file is not even recognized.

Comment: The error says that file does not even exist. That could be the reason why it can't be read ;)

Comment: Exactly, so, why It cannot be uploaded as any of the other files? Te form and the uploading code is the same, so the problem is the csv file itself. How can I understand more about what can go wrong with a csv file?

Comment: ??? It can not be uploaded because it doesn't exist. Something in your code for generating those CSV files seems to be wrong and not generate `importar.csv`.

Comment: That's the problem: it's not the code but the csv file. I've tried several other csv files and they all upload without issues. What can go wrong with a csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the failed upload, the provided error number is 1. [Looking at the official list of error codes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), error number 1 is:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

So you'll need to increase the `upload_max_filesize` option in your php.ini.